# Ubuntu 19.04 not booting

Tags: boot

Ubuntu 19.04 is stuck at the ubuntu logo on the boot sequence. I installed it on a Dell Latitude E6540 as the main operating system (not in VirtualBox). It worked normally for few days, and since last night the computer never boots up and gets stuck at this screen.

[image: 5 dots ubuntu logo]

Please help to recover it.

Comment: Have you tried recovery mode and tried to use older kernel or have tried booting from install media?

Answer (score 1):

Hold <kbd>shift</kbd> while booting up if grub menu doesn't appear automatically, once you're in the grub menu, press <kbd>E</kbd> while you are selecting Ubuntu. Add `nomodeset` after **quiet splash** in the line which starts with `linux`. This will disable the graphic drivers which I believe is the problem here. Once you boot up, in order to permanently change your grub options, open a terminal and write:

```
sudo leafpad /etc/default/grub
```

*Change `leafpad` for whatever text editor you use, might be `gedit`!*

Search for the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Change it to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`

Head to a terminal and type `sudo update-grub`

As your question is not a 100% clear and I don't know if you have a dedicated GPU, I believe this is a graphic driver error, so my solution relies on disabling them. However you could just enter Ubuntu using the solution given, then instead of editing grub, simply install your proprietary drivers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I will try this fix today.

Comment: The graphics card:   Intel HD graphics 4600 with Ex press Card

Comment: Then you should be good to go doing the steps shown before. You are welcome!